# Lua Logitech How to have script NOT repeat when button is pressed?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to have the below code execute the MoveMouseRelative function only once when mouse button 1 is pressed or held. I've tried removing the "repeat" line but it breaks the code. Currently when activated and mouse 1 is held the cursor is dragged down constantly.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)  -- to prevent it from being stuck on
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
        recoilx2 = not recoilx2
        spot = not spot
    end
   if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoilx2) then
        if recoilx2 then
            repeat
                --Sleep(35)
                Sleep(5)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 3)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Remove both `repeat` and `until` lines

Comment: Anyway I can PM you? or email or discord or something?

Answer (score 0):

> Goal: Lua script for Logitech mouse that performs the following tasks:
>      When mouse button 5 has been "activated":
>        - Left clicks once every 1000 milliseconds (time in between shots),
>        - and also pulls the mouse down once every 1000 milliseconds.
>      So if I hold left mouse button it continuously shoots but only pulls down when it does shoot

Select a keyboard button you never use in the game and set it as the only way to fire the pistol, this key will be used to fire programmatically.
I assume the key is <kbd>P</kbd>, but you can choose any other button: "f12", "backspace", "num9", ...
The game must do nothing on left mouse button press.

```
local fire_button = "P"

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
      -- to prevent mouse buttons from being stuck on
      for j = 1, 5 do ReleaseMouseButton(j) end
   end
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      recoilx2 = not recoilx2
   end
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      PressKey(fire_button)
      Sleep(50)
      ReleaseKey(fire_button)
      if recoilx2 then
         while IsMouseButtonPressed(1) do
            MoveMouseRelative(0, 25)
            local next_shot_time = GetRunningTime() + 1000
            local LMB
            repeat
               Sleep(50)
               LMB = IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            until not LMB or GetRunningTime() >= next_shot_time
            if LMB then
               PressKey(fire_button)
               Sleep(50)
               ReleaseKey(fire_button)
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I never would of thought to make it that way! Very smart, but unfortunately after setting P as a secondary fire option in game it doesn't continue to shoot while holding left mouse button.

Comment: Actually if I set main and secondary keybind to P for fire then it works, but I am unable to fire on my own.

Comment: Does it mean that (with Logitech profile disabled) when you keep LMB pressed, the P key is ignored by the game?  Please check that the following sequence produces exactly two pistol shots: Press LMB (first shot), Press and release P (second shot), Release LMB.

Comment: Yes. When the left mouse button is held down, and i press P it doesnt shoot again (ignores). When I hold P, and press left mouse it doesnt shoot again (ignores).

Comment: I think for this to work, the script has to: constantly press and release either left mouse button or P(prefer left mouse only) while also executing a movemouse function to pulldown. I've had press/release function work while holding down left mouse button in the game, i just cant find a way to script in a mouse pulldown while that is happening.

Comment: Script updated.  Set the key `P` as the only way to fire the pistol in the game.  The game must ignore left mouse button.